# Python BeautifulSoup HTML parse code select

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
         response = requests.get(f"https://steamid.io/lookup/" f"{on_message}")
         steamid = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
         print(steamid.prettify())
```

When I run the code, the codes of the site are written as html

```
<table class="table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
         <td style="width:40%">
          a steamID
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           STEAM_0:0:11101
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a steamID3
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           [U:1:22202]
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a steamID3 without brackets
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           U:1:22202
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a steamID64
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           76561197960287930
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a customURL
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           gabelogannewell
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a full URL
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197960287930
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a full URL with customURL
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           http://steamcommunity.com/id/gabelogannewell
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       <p>
        <br/>
        Regular names as input may work and will yield a limited list of profiles, but only if the matching customURL is not taken. customURLs always prevail.
       </p>
       <p>
        Trade URLs will
        <i>
         NOT
        </i>
        work.
       </p>
       <p>
        To convert or look up multiple values, use the dropdown arrow to select
        <i>
         extended list
        </i>
        .
       </p>
      </div>
     </section>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I want to parse and select the following part from those codes

```
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          a steamID64
         </td>
         <td>
          <code>
           76561197960287930
          </code>
         </td>
        </tr>
```

I want to parse and select the section that says "76561197960287930" from here, how can I do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome at stack overflow :) Well, the number that you want to extract is inside a `<code>` node. However, there are multiple such nodes in your html, so what makes the section that you want to select different from the other sections (such as, e.g., `STEAM_0:0:11101`)?

Comment: i want steamID64
all steamID64 starts with 765611

Comment: I see. Could you please provide a complete code example that we can run to reproduce your output.

Comment: Note that when you perform actual lookup the resulting page source is different. what you show are the examples for lookup values.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: when I run code, codes of whole page are written, I just wrote the specific section

Comment: You show the source code from https://steamid.io/lookup/ where a `table` tag is present. when you perform specific lookup, e.g. https://steamid.io/lookup/STEAM_0:0:11105 the source code is different.

Comment: yes, another page opens according to the `{on_message}` value entered. I want to have the steamID64 code selected from there.

Comment: Entering `{on_message}` a value like `https://steamcommunity.com/id/chef31/`

Comment: fixed it, thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find a `<tr>` that contains the text *"a steamID64"* and find the `<code>` tag:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.select_one("tr:-soup-contains('a steamID64') code").get_text(strip=True)
)
```

Output:

```
76561197960287930z
```

Comment: it only returns 76561197960287930 instead of steamID64 in `{on_message}` value entered

Comment: @TurgutCecen So what's the expected output exactly?

Comment: fixed it, thanks for ur help

Comment: can u  look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70762382/python-beautifulsoup-html-parse-class-select) the output html has changed ?