# Python BeautifulSoup HTML parse class select

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if message.content.startswith("https:"):
         response = requests.get(f"https://steamid.io/lookup/" f"{msg}")
         soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
         print(soup.prettify())
```

When I run the code, the codes of the site are written as html

```
  </div>
  <dl class="panel-body dl-horizontal">
   <dt class="key">
    steamID
   </dt>
   <dd class="value short">
    <img alt="copy to clipboard" class="cp" data-clipboard-text="STEAM_0:0:444916529" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" src="https://steamid.io/static/img/copy.png" title="copy to clipboard"/>
    <a href="https://steamid.io/lookup/STEAM_0:0:444916529" id="a" rel="nofollow">
     STEAM_0:0:444916529
    </a>
   </dd>
   <dt class="key">
    steamID3
   </dt>
   <dd class="value short">
    <img alt="copy to clipboard" class="cp" data-clipboard-text="[U:1:889833058]" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" src="https://steamid.io/static/img/copy.png" title="copy to clipboard"/>
    <a href="https://steamid.io/lookup/[U:1:889833058]" rel="nofollow">
     [U:1:889833058]
    </a>
   </dd>
   <dt class="key">
    steamID64
   </dt>
   <dd class="value short">
    <img alt="copy to clipboard" class="cp" data-clipboard-text="76561198850098786" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" src="https://steamid.io/static/img/copy.png" title="copy to clipboard"/>
    <a href="https://steamid.io/lookup/76561198850098786">
     76561198850098786
    </a>
   </dd>
   <dt class="key">
    customURL
   </dt>
   <dd class="value short">
    not set
   </dd>
   <dt class="key">
    profile state
   </dt>
```

I want to parse and select the following part from those codes

```
<dt class="key">
    steamID64
   </dt>
   <dd class="value short">
    <img alt="copy to clipboard" class="cp" data-clipboard-text="76561198850098786" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" src="https://steamid.io/static/img/copy.png" title="copy to clipboard"/>
    <a href="https://steamid.io/lookup/76561198850098786">
     76561198850098786
    </a>
```

I want to parse and select the section that says "76561198850098786" from here, how can I do it?

Comment: Please provide  the full link / couple of links for testing purposes.

Comment: full links like this : `https://steamid.io/lookup/https://steamcommunity.com/id/fatiihimm/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:-soup-contains` to target the element with class `key` containing the term `steamID64`, then use an adjacent sibling combinator to move to the adjacent element with class `value`, then a child combinator to move to the `a` tag having the desired value

```
soup.select_one('.key:-soup-contains("steamID64") + .value > a').text
```

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help